# How to force scroll in overflow-y div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm trying to force an offset scroll in a div that contain a ngfor list

I tried this on the div that as the overflow-y:

```
@ViewChild('list') listRef: ElementRef;
```

then on click I try this with some log to be sure it's called

```
this.listRef.nativeElement.offsetTop = 500;
```

Nothing happens, any idea how I can achieve this ?

EDIT :

Html :

```
<div
  #gridContainerId
  class="gridContainer">
  <a *ngFor="let item of images;">
     <img src="{{getImage(item)}}"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

css :

```
.gridContainer {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

component :

```
@ViewChild('gridContainerId') ref: ElementRef;

this.store.pipe(
      select(fromImages.getImages),
      takeWhile(() => this.componentActive)
    ).subscribe(imagesItems => {
        this.images = imagesItems;
        updateScroll();
      }
    );

updateScroll(){
  this.ref.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.ref.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently in your same scenario, when click certain button, the div scrolled to bottom, i achieved it with this code:

```
this.messagesContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.messagesContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

the property scrollTop is to specify the number of pixels to be scrolled from the top of the view.
and the property scrollHeight is to get the total height of the div.

Comment: I tried that on the container that have the overflow and nothing happens :/

Comment: i guess the issue here that you are scrolling before the view is rendered,
you need to add it inside setTimeout in order to be executed after the view is rendered and take its actual height

Comment: I can share bits of code, but I can't include everything and I have to rename it. Confidentiality issues.

Comment: I tried with a 2000ms timeout same result nothing happens, the list is loaded and rendered in less than  100ms